# Which prison cells will remain open in the following problem involving a drunken jailor?

Tags: probability

Suppose we have $100$ prison cells initially all locked. A drunken jailor chooses an integer $i$ uniformly randomly from the interval $\left[1,100\right]$ and then opens every $i$-th cell. On any succeeding round he repeats the same procedure and toggles every $i$-th  cell (all integer $i$'s are chosen independently). Find the expression for the probability   of the $n$-th cell being open on the $j$-th round, $n$ and $j$ being given.

Comment: Hint: Opening $n$-th cell on $i$-th round means toggling (opening or shutting) other $n-1$ cells on the previous $i-1$ rounds.

Comment: please note it is jth round and not ith round.i is the random integr the jailor choses from the interval[1,100] on each round. nth ceell will remain open ofter the jth round if it was locked on the (j-1)th  round and the integer i chosen on jth round is a divisor of n

Comment: Sorry for misread. Could you clarify "every ith cell"? E.g. every 5th cell, is opening (a) 1, 6, 11,... or (b) 5, 10, 15, ... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability of toggling door $n$ in any particular round is $\dfrac{d(n)}{100}$ where $d(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$.

Therefore, the $j$ rounds are a binomial process with $$p=\frac{d(n)}{100}$$ and being open means having been chosen an odd number of times.

This is given by $$\sum_{k}p^{2k+1}(1-p)^{j-2k-1}\binom{j}{2k+1}=\frac{1-(1-2p)^j}2$$ for the $p$ given above.

Comment: Correct answer. I'll never attempt to answer again when I feel dizzy :)

Comment: @Phira  the answer tells us that the probability of different doors being open on jth round is different(being a function of door number).Can you please tell me how we can find the expected no. of open doors on the jth round  and more interestingly when  j goes to infinity?

Comment: @sajjadveeri I am sorry, I had an error in my expression which I fixed now. Clearly, the probability tends to $\frac12$ as it should, so the expected number at infinity is $50$.

Comment: @sajjadveeri I do not think that it is possible to give a closed-form expression for the expected number after each round, so you will just have to write down the series $\sum_n  n Pr(X=n)$ as usual.

Comment: thank u for the  elegant solution